# React native WebView is not loading the react js site (built in react js)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React native WebView is not loading the react js site (built in react js)?

React native WebView is not loading the react site (built in react)?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import Configuration from '../config/configuration';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { lightGreyColor, redColor } from '../constants';

export default class PaymentWebView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.config = new Configuration();

        this.state = {
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <WebView
                style={{ width: '100%',marginTop: 20, background: redColor }}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
                // renderLoading={<ActivityIndicator />}
                startInLoadingState={true}
                scalesPageToFit={true}
                source={{ uri: 'https://autodeals-web.firebaseapp.com/' }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using webview from react-native-community/react-native-webview?
can you post your entire component?

Comment: @tajammul1996 full component added

Comment: I tried your implementation and it works fine with other URL but your site even doesn't load on my browser.. might be issue with the site. your implementation for webview looks good though.

Comment: @tajammul1996 did you try it with react js site?

Comment: yes, I tried using https://docs-on-blocks.netlify.app/ which is built on reactjs..

Comment: @tajammul1996 then why its creating issue on my url, I am using lazyloading on react js app, it might be creating issue?

Comment: Not sure but am not able to access your site on my browser too.

Comment: @tajammul1996 which browser?

Comment: Chrome on laptop, it just  stuck on that loading wheel.

Comment: @tajammul1996 you can check, site is loading fine now, but i think loader overlay might be the problem

Comment: do you found any solution?

Comment: I need to implement some funcitonality

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  BackHandler,
  Platform,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';
class HelpWebView extends Component {
  webView = {
    canGoBack: false,
    ref: null,
  };
  loader = {
    show: true,
  };
  onAndroidBackPress = () => {
    if (this.webView.canGoBack && this.webView.ref) {
      this.webView.ref.goBack();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        this.onAndroidBackPress,
      );
    } else {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backHandler);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
    } else {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backHandler);
    }
  }

  backHandler = () => {
    this.webView.ref.goBack();
    return true;
  };

  ActivityIndicatorLoadingView() {
    return (
      <ActivityIndicator
        color="#009688"
        size="large"
        style={styles.ActivityIndicatorStyle}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        style={styles.WebViewStyle}
        onLoadEnd={() => {
          this.loader.show = false;
        }}
        injectedJavaScript={`const meta = document.createElement('meta'); meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=0'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta); `}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
        scrollEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        renderLoading={this.ActivityIndicatorLoadingView}
        startInLoadingState={true}
        bounces={false}
        source={{uri: 'https://autodeals-web.firebaseapp.com/'}}
        ref={(webView) => {
          this.webView.ref = webView;
        }}
        sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
        javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
        userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36"
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  WebViewStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 0,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    flex: 1,
  },

  ActivityIndicatorStyle: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default HelpWebView;
```